How do I put white highlights on these eyes?
I have eyes where the pupils disappear when they go beyond the black circle of the eyes. Romain Guimbal , from this site, helped me achieve this. I don’t really understand the process but I followed his words and image and it works great.
My new problem is I want a white highlight on each pupil that moves with the pupil and also disappears beyond the black eye circles. I don’t know how to do this. I don’t know Blender or other programs that well so please pretend you’re talking to an 8 year old. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. Blender 4.1.1  Image:Eyes how they are and how I want them and the shader nodes.

"Any help would be appreciated" - really?

@Gordon Brinkmann I really do appreciate your help. I'm just trying to figure this out at this moment. I haven't had time to really look at this. It was a long weekend. I didn't want to get back to you until after I worked on this because I may have questions. The amount of work you put in to helping me is above and beyond. I'm sorry if you felt unappreciated or just blown off. I always thank people who help me. The next question that someone answers me, I'll be sure to thank them promptly. Sorry and thank you so much for helping me. I'll let you know how I did. Thanks.

@Gordon Brinkmann Hi. Thanks again for your help. Most of what you said was beyond my knowledge but I duplicated your shader nodes, adjusted values sort of randomly and figured it out. Duplicating the eye wasn’t working so I appended the eye and did some parenting and low and behold it works! Thank you so much. The world is a better place knowing that a stranger will take an interest in a noobs project and do the amount of work that you did to help. You’re very kind. Thanks. Jeff.

In which way did duplicating not work? In my setup it works...?

When I duplicated the eye, shift+D or just duplicate, it wouldn't have the iris, the black dot. There's nothing too specific that you wrote that's confusing, I have a hard time following most of it. It was the nodes that helped. I'm sure your setup works fine but I wasn't doing something correctly I'm sure. Regardless, for my purposes which are very basic, my eyes now do what I wanted them to do. Thanks again. (o:

If there is something else that is missing why you won't accept the answer let me know so I can improve it.

I do accept the answer.Your image of nodes is what helped. It's what you wrote that is beyond my understanding. A lot of people would have no problem understanding what you wrote. For me to understand you'd have to say in the simplest terms, " Make this in this mode, and then press this and then go to this page and...". I don't have a clue as to where to put the nodes in what order. I've been learning through Youtube videos. The complex stuff doesn't stay with me. I just get lost. When something comes up I need to figure out I tackle that problem by finding the most basic video on the subject.

Please read: What should I do if someone answers my question?

@Gordon Brinkmann  I didn't know that. Thanks.

The highlight is created very similar. Instead of using a Greater Than to make a black circle on a white background you make it Less Than to get a white circle on a black background.
Then you just have to use a Vector Math node set to Add before the Length node and change the X and Z values until the highlight has the offset from the center you like.
To combine the pupil and the highlight you use a Math node set to Maximum. This will keep the white highlight over the black pupil and the white background.
Apart from that, I do not know how you have created the black border around the eye, I did this here with the original object's coordinates and a Less Than node, multiplying this with the pupil will make sure that the border stays black no matter if there is a highlight or not.

Here I am moving the empty to move the pupil:

//EDIT: Okay, I could not resist. The problem with the basic setup is, it breaks as soon as the eye moves or rotates or scales. To avoid that, the initial constellation should be, both objects are reset and in the same location. Then the empty should be parented to the eye. This way, you can move the empty relative to the eye, so that it still controls the pupil, but the eye controls where and how everything is located, rotated and scaled.
So far so good. Now what do you do if you want two (or three or four?) eyes all controlled by a single empty? As it is in this moment, you would have to create a new material for a second eye, referencing the empty and take into account that the second eye is not in the smae place as the first. And of course rotating would mess up everything, too.
But if you want to place, rotate and scale the second eye independently from the original eye? And of course everything with a single material, so that you can duplicate the eye and keep the material, not always having to give it a new one.
There it gets a bit more complicated ;) You need a setup to create eye border, pupil and highlight for the current object - which might be a duplicate or the original eye.
To place everything correctly on the mesh even if it is a duplicate in a different place etc., you have to add the current object's coordinates to the Empty's coordinates and subtract those of the original eye for creating the pupil and the highlight in the same position as the original eye.
Now you can create as many duplicates of the eye as you like and move, rotate and scale them as you wish. Note that in order to work the transformations should not be applied on the objects. By the way, I have "outsourced" the values for the pupil sizing and positioning, but of course this is not necessary as they could be changed in the math nodes directly.

So now you can duplicate the main eye and rotate or scale it and the pupils stay where they should:

And they are all controlled by a single Empty parented to the main eye:


